# YUI animate one div and fade in another

Tags: javascript, yui

I need to animate the div 'introduction' to make its height and width zero when clicked on the link 'click here to begin', which works. Another div 'theTest' needs to fade in at the same event. Unfortunately it is not working.
I am new to YUI and I used [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/animation/basic.html) as the source.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pV8eT/1/

Code:

```
(function() {
    var introductionAttributes = {
        width: { to: 0 },
        height: { to: 0 }
    };
    var theTestAttributes = {
        visible: { to: true },
        width: { to: 500 },
        height: { to: 500 }
    };
    var introductionAnim = new YAHOO.util.Anim('introduction', introductionAttributes);
    var theTestAnim = new YAHOO.util.Anim('theTest', theTestAttributes);

    YAHOO.util.Event.on('startTest', 'click', function() {
        introductionAnim.animate();   //this works
        theTestAnim.animate();        //this doesnt work :(
    });
})();
```

How do I modify the code to fade in the div "theTest" ?

Comment: Is YUI 2 a requirement? Can you switch to YUI 3?

Comment: Yes, I can switch to YUI 3.

Comment: Then I'd recommend you try YUI 3. YUI 2 is no longer supported by either Yahoo! or the community. Also, in terms of animations, it comes with a `transition` module which uses CSS transitions for smoother animations when available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is with `display: none` and visibility. But I wouldn't know how to fix it because my YUI 2 knowledge is limited.

Here how I'd do it in YUI3:

```
YUI().use('transition', function (Y) {
  var introduction = Y.one('#introduction'),
      test = Y.one('#theTest');

  Y.one('#startTest').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    introduction.transition({
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    });
    // first set display to block, then change opacity
    // so it fades in
    test.setStyle('display', 'block').transition({
      opacity: 1
    });
  });
});
```

I also added `opacity: 0` to the CSS style of `#theTest`.

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/odujer/1

Comment: Looks great! :) How can we add the fade in effect to 'theTest' div?

Comment: I made it fade by setting `opacity: 0` in the CSS (you'll need to add a filter in IE) and then transitioning `opacity` to `1`. You can change the duration of the transition with `duration: 100` where 100 are seconds